# intuitive proof regarding measure of single element set on a continuous distribution

Tags: measure-theory

I'm brushing up on measure theory and was hoping to get a somewhat intuitive explanation of the following.

Suppose that $\Omega = [0, \infty)$ and our $\sigma$-algebra $A = \mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$ -- namely the sigma algebra generated by the open sets of $\Omega$.

The continuous measure of $P([0,x)) = 1-e^{-x}\; \forall x>0$ is a valid continuous measure.

I see that the $Pr([0,x) \cup [x,y))$ = Pr([0,y]) so it satisfies the additivity property.

Now, I know form basic probability that $Pr(x) = Pr({x}) = 0$ (since this is just the exponential distribution).

Is there a way to intuitively see this from the measure theory approach?

I get that $[0,x)$ can not be written as a countable union of individual elements but I'm looking for something deeper.

Thanks!

Comment: From the fact that $[0,x] = [0,y] \cup (y,x]$ for every $y < x$, we see that $P(\{x\}) \leq P((y,x]) = P([0,x]) - P([0,y])$, which can be made arbitrarily small, and hence $P(\{x\})$ has to be zero. Is that intuitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Measures are monotone: if $A \subset B$ and $A,B$ are measurable then $P(A) \le P(B)$. In the present example if $y > x$ then
$$0 \le P(\{x\}) \le P([x,y)) = e^{-x} - e^{-y}.$$
The only way this can hold for **all** is for $P(\{x\}) = 0$.

Comment: Can you just say, letting x = y, you get 0 <= P({x}) <= P([x,x)) = 0 which implies P({x}) = 0?

Comment: Not quite. $[x,x) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Argh -- of course -- and here I thought I was being clever. But would that not mean we can only talk about P({x}) in the limit, as I would need to do some delta-epsilon argument? I see that I can make P({x}) arbitrarily small but that does not mean 0, unless in the limit no?

Comment: No, the delta-epsilon stuff is low-level and is extremely useful, but the limit laws exist for a reason. Since $e^{-y} \to e^{-x}$ as $y \to x^+$ you can use the squeeze theorem. $P(\{x\})$ has a well-defined value, and the squeeze theorem tells you it must be $0$.

Comment: Ah! Yep -- got it. That's at least one step up from my delta-epsilon argument. Many thanks!

Comment: thinking more on this: The squeeze theorem tells you that the one sided limit of P({x}) exists and is 0. That doesn't tell you the actual value is 0 no?

Comment: No, $P(\{x\})$ is a specific number that is both $\ge 0$ and $\le$ something that has a $0$ one-sided limit. That means it must equal $0$. If you must, argue by contradiction. If $P(\{x\}) > 0$, just choose $y > x$ so close to $x$ that $e^{-x} - e^{-y} < P(\{x\})$ and voila--a contradiction.